# Create mixture LazyVGrid and List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there a possibility to have a mixture of LazyVGrid and a List, with alternating two Grid items and two List items for example?

Comment: can you provide some image which describes how u want to arrange views ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List{
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())], content: {
                Text("Placeholder")
                Text("Placeholder")
            })
            Text("Text")
            Text("Text")
        }
    }
}
```